# Trouble with text-wrapping in d3.js when appending text to svg

Tags: html, css, svg, d3.js

I'm having some issues formatting text in d3 -- I'm appending text to an svg. Ultimately, I want it to look something like this:

[image]

I've gotten fairly close with the following:

```
var margin = {top: 40, right: 0, bottom: 40, left: 0},
    width = width - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = height - margin.top - margin.bottom;
    

    
var svg = div.append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");
    
var g = svg.append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

var data_access_group = "Ashland County"
var numCases = "26"
var firstYr = "2017"
var lastDate = "6/16/2022"
     

   var text = svg.append("text")
  .attr("dy", 0)
  .attr("x",0)
  .attr("font-weight", 400)
  .text("Overdose Fatalities Among Residents of ")
  .attr("class", "overview-text")
  .attr("id", "overview-text-1")
  .append("tspan")
  .attr("font-weight", 900)
  .text(data_access_group)
  .attr("class", "overview-text")
  

  
  
  
  svg.append("text")
    .attr("class", "overview-text")
    .attr("id", "overview-text-2")
    .attr("dy", "3.8em")
    .attr("x",0)
    .attr("font-weight", 900)
    .text(numCases)
    .append("tspan")
    .attr("font-weight", 400)
    .text(" overdose fatalities since ")
    .append("tspan")
    .attr("font-weight", 900)
    .text(firstYr)
    
      svg.append("text")
    .attr("class", "overview-text")
    .attr("id", "overview-text-3")
    .attr("dy", "8.8em")
    .attr("x",0)
    .attr("font-weight", 400)
    .text("Includes only resident fatalities. Most recent overdose fatality: "+ lastDate)
```

**CSS**

```
#overview-text-1 {
  font-size:30px !important;
  
}
```

But this produces something like this:

[image]

You can see that the text is not wrapping; i.e. the text is getting cut off.  I've tried this:

```
function wrap(text, width) {
  text.each(function() {
    var text = d3.select(this),
        words = text.text().split(/\s+/).reverse(),
        word,
        line = [],
        lineNumber = 0,
        lineHeight = 1.1, // ems
        y = text.attr("y"),
        dy = parseFloat(text.attr("dy")),
        tspan = text.text(null).append("tspan").attr("x", 0).attr("y", y).attr("dy", dy + "em");
    while (word = words.pop()) {
      line.push(word);
      tspan.text(line.join(" "));
      if (tspan.node().getComputedTextLength() > width) {
        line.pop();
        tspan.text(line.join(" "));
        line = [word];
        tspan = text.append("tspan").attr("x", 0).attr("y", y).attr("dy", ++lineNumber * lineHeight + dy + "em").text(word);
      }
    }
  });
} 

setTimeout(()=>{
  d3.selectAll(".overview-text")
    .call(wrap,500);
  }, 0);
```

But it's still not working as it should.  Basically, I just want this text to wrap so that it's not cut off when I resize.  I am open to a better approach in general to producing the desired text.

Comment: SVG `<text>` is really bad at wrapping. Can you include the data as HTML instead?

Comment: Hi, thanks.  Can you please post an example?  I tried giving the svg a class of "svg" and then using: d3.select('.svg').html()

Comment: Essentially, you would use [`<foreignObject>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/foreignObject) with regular HTML tags inside.

Comment: @Tigt thanks- you are right - SVG text wrapping is pretty bad.  I followed your advice and essentially used something to the effect of d3.select(#container).html and then just used html.  Worked much easier and more intuitive then using SVG text.  Thanks!